# Incorrect routing with optional parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I wanted to extend a controller action to accept an optional parameter. In other words I wanted existing code to continue to work but add some new functionality that would pass additional information. I modified my routeprovider, controller, and tested it. The optional parameter and routing all worked great. So I did a regression test to see that existing code would still work and you guessed it. It didn't.

So what am I doing wrong / not understanding? I thought I could use the existing controller action and it would work with or without the optional parameter?

I have not posted my controller code as I don't believe that is coming into play. I set my breakpoint on the first line and never get there so it seems to me my routeprovider has an error. If other code is needed I will gladly add it.

this works: domain.com/signup/12345

this doesn't but used to work just fine: domain.com/signup

```
routes.MapLocalizedRoute("SignUp", "signup/{CampaignId}",
new {controller="Customer", action="NewSignup", CampaignId=UrlParameter.Optional},
new { CampaignId = @"\d+" },
new[] { "Domain.PROJECT.Controllers" });
```

So I would like the two url samples above to work. I can of course add another route without the campaignid and point it to the same controller action but again...I THOUGHT...that was the idea behind making the campaignid optional???

Does the new { CampaignId = @"\d+" }, object constraint override the optional parameter and basically force the campaignid to exist?

Thank You

Comment: `new { CampaignId = @"\d*" }` should do it.

Comment: @shakib That didn't break anything but it didn't allow the route to operate with / without the parameter.

Comment: maybe i misunderstood, but with the default route handler i.e. `MvcRouteHandler`, using constraint `new { CampaignId = @"\d*" }` supports `site.com/signup` and `site.com/signup/` and `site.com/signup/123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define two routes.

One requiring the campaingId:

```
routes.MapLocalizedRoute("SignUpCampaign", "signup/{CampaignId}",
                         new { controller="Customer", action="NewSignup" },
                         new { CampaignId = @"\d+" },
                         new[] { "Domain.PROJECT.Controllers" });
```

And one not requiring it:

```
routes.MapLocalizedRoute("SignUp", "signup",
                         new { controller="Customer", action="NewSignup" },
                         null,
                         new[] { "Domain.PROJECT.Controllers" });
```

Comment: I agree that would work but is that a band-aid? See I don't know so I'm not questioning you just trying to understand.

Comment: I wasn't sure if the route would match if you have an optional parameter and a constraint on that parameter. Little bit of research shows that it will never match: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468115/optional-routing-parameter-with-constraint-in-asp-net-mvc-2